# PIC32 Assign Port Bit to Variable (in C)

Tags: pic

The pins i connect some LEDs to might change during the development (and routing) so I would like to assign the Port bits to a variable (so if the LED has to be connected to another port I only have to change port assigned to the variable and instead of updating each call in the code).

I would like to do some kind of the following in C:

```
#define myvariable = PORTB.RB11;
#define myvariable2 = PORTB.RB12;

main(){
    if(...)  myvariable = 1;     // B11 is HIGH
    else myvariable = 0;         // B11 is LOW
    if(...)  myvariable2 = 1;
    else myvariable2 = 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'd be happy if you could post the two lines of code. (assignment and usage)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the device header file you should find unions defined to access individual bits of IO and other registers.

e.g. from Pic24 code - not sure if PIC32 is the same

```
#define thepin LATBbits.LATB13

thepin=0;
```

Comment: thanks! It worked perfectly!

comment for beginners (like me): don't add any semicolon after a #define statement!! - that costed me 20 min..:D

Then the code works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a lot of defines and structures with enumerations to prevent my code from being tied to a particular peripheral, or sometimes a particular microcontroller family.  The below code assumes outputting a 1 turns the LED on, and a 0 turns it off.  By using defines, you are less likely to get these things confused when coding and debugging.

```
 #define LED1_TRIS (TRISAbits.TRISA1)
 #define LED1_IO (PORTAbits.RA1)
 #define SET_INPUT (1)
 #define SET_OUTPUT (0)
 #define LED_ON (1)
 #define LED_OFF (0)

 /* Set as an output. */
 LED1_TRIS = SET_OUTPUT;
 /* Turn LED on. */
 LED1_IO = LED_ON;
 /* Wait. */
 Nop();
 /* Turn LED off. */
 LED1_IO = LED_OFF;
```